# Robin Herbots Inputmask Date Limits

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

Do I understand correctly that Robin Herbots Inputmask only works for dates between 1900 and 2099?
I want to use it to help the user enter dates before 1900 and be sure about the format. I don't particularly care if the user enters a leap year when there wasn't a leap year, or thinks that there are 31 days in September. Thanks.

Comment: 1 - have you consulted the documentation and contacted the devs? 2 - Have you tried to amend the source to deal with this yourself?

Comment: I have consulted the documentation, but there isn't much of it and it isn't clear enough - for me, anyway. I don't immediately know how to contact the developers and I think it would probably be simpler to do it myself than amend the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 33 of **/js/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js** - simply edit the years by century match from `(19|20)` to whatever you need so for years 1700 - 2299 so..

```
'y': { //basic year
  validator: "(17|18|19|20|21|22)\\d{2}",
  cardinality: 4,
  prevalidator: [
    { validator: "[12]", cardinality: 1 },
    { validator: "(17|18|19|20|21|22)", cardinality: 2 },
    { validator: "(17|18|19|20|21|22)\\d", cardinality: 3 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get it to work for dates before 1800. If it's that easy to extend I don't see why the user should be limited in the first place. You use these things to save time and if they don't work out of the box you may as well do it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I could get it to work below 1800, but the rest of my comments still apply. Thanks again.

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as correct. Now, you do have an unfortunate opinion about free plugins. They are designed to serve a general purpose. This is one of only a handful that are actually easy to manipulate however if a developer is not getting rewarded for their work for the community, who are we to place such a demand on them. Plugins are not designed to be specific to your particular case. They provide a starting block, if it works perfect for your needs then great otherwise, taking exactly 10 seconds (how long it took me) to amend a tiny piece of code is your responsibility

Comment: I don't know how to "mark it as correct". Previously I have commented that the issue is closed, but I don't know if that is the same. My comments were not derogatory. This looks like a fine bit of code, but for someone of my level of expertise, it's a bit short on documentation. And I would imagine there are plenty of other people with my level of expertise. I come from a mainly engineering background where there are lots of superior bits of equipment that never get used because there is inferior equipment with a better user interface.

Comment: There is a tick to the left of my answer, just under the "upvote" number to mark it as the answer. You'll find this a lot. Using free plugins (as well as premium ones) come on the understanding that the user has a certain level of experience in the area in order to use it most effectively. I appreciate the analogy of engineering tools but as a complete layman in that particular area, I couldn't have a moan because I do not have enough knowledge to use an "inferior" or "superior" piece of equipment. You study what you don't understand. Just relying on plugins to complete a task, you'll struggle

Comment: I've just ticked this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

Solution:
$(".datemask").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy", "yearrange":{minyear: 1600, maxyear: 2099 }});